# Autostart is not working after power outage

Tags: ubuntu, boot, graphics-card, gpu, power

I have NVIDIA RTX 6000 Ada graphics card and Asus PRO WS WRX80E-SAGE SE motherboard in my workstation. I enabled `Restore AC Power Loss` on BIOS settings. When I power off and on the system using PSU switch or power button, the system boots automatically with no problem. But when I unplug, or there is a power outage, the system is stuck in a black screen, although it autostarts. And when I restart using the PSU switch or power button, it can boot again. I'm suspicious that it can be related to connection type (I'm using Displayport). But I'm open to any suggestions.

Comment: That's really odd. As far as the computer goes, there's zero difference between pulling the plug and toggling the PSU switch! If there is a difference, that would mean the switch does not isolate the power supply from the cable.

Comment: A short press on the power button is equivalent to an orderly shutdown, only a long press causes a brutal turn off. If on Windows, try to test integrity by running the commands [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu @harrymc

Comment: I added ubuntu to your tags.